# AS3 embedded fonts inside swfs loaded into application sandbox - odd behaviour

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts, air

I'm seeing some very mysterious font behaviour in AS3, Air App, using Flash version 11.5, compiling my fla files in Flash Pro CC 2014.

**Context:** Air application, shell loads swfs at runtime as 'modules', into the application domain (so they are run as if they were part of the main app, not as children inside a sandbox).

**Problem:** Some dynamic textfields containing embedded fonts in some of the loaded swfs are not appearing, while others are fine.

**Details:**

- This is a new problem - fonts that were fine a few weeks ago are now misbehaving. (Same computer, same OS and Flash version)
- The same font that is missing in some 'modules' (swfs) is present in others.
- Some fonts from the same family work everywhere (Myriad Pro Semibold), others are missing in some places, but present in others (Myriad Pro Regular)
- All the TextFields are inside movieclips that are then pulled in to the swfs at compile time using

`[Embed(source="someFla.swf", symbol="libraryExportName")]`

- The Air 'shell' contains and successfully uses Myriad Pro Semi, Myriad Pro Regular and Arial. (Only)
- Some fonts appear fine locally during test, but then disappear once the Air app is installed (Myriad Pro Regular)
- Other fonts are consistently rubbish - Helvetica Neue for example, disappeared in multiple places in test as well as once installed
- All the fonts are embedded as required in the individual swfs (Basic Latin set) but not exported for actionscript as the fonts are set at compile time rather than at run time.

If anyone has any insights or suggestions that would be great. My hunch is that the fonts that are embedded into multiple swfs are somehow 'clashing', but I can't unravel why I get some clashes while others are fine. I've wrangled font embedding in flash for many years and I've tried everything I can think of to overcome the usual gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding fonts always leads to some problems if you compile to multiple platforms  (iOS, Android, Air, EXE, Flash), and there's only 1 solution that works (at least, we haven't had any problems since we moved to this solution):

1. include a TextField in your project, 1 per specific non-system font that you're using (fontAwesome, WebDings, etc.; we tend to call them `_webdings`, `_awesome`, etc)
2. Copy all specific characters that you're using to that textfield during designtime
3. Hide the textfields upon boot (`_webdings.visible = _awesome.visible = false`)
4. Ignore ALL "you must include"-messages as the chars you're using will be automatically included in your swf when compiling...